# Queued route() urls has wrong domain in URL

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.1

I have a Laravel 5.1 application that has many clients with their own unique subdomains and databases.

On app loading, my middlewares resolves the client and sets the app.url (config/app.php) accordingly. It all works great, in the browser. All urls generated by route() has the correct subdomain for current client.

But, stuff queued (Redis in my case) will always defaults to a domain URL of "localhost".

So if I send a welcome email where the text template contains route('account') it will from the queue generate a "http://localhost/account" URL. This is of course not correct.

I've found the line that probably does this, it's in the Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\SetRequestForConsole class:

```
$url = $app->make('config')->get('app.url', 'http://localhost'); <---
```

As far as I can see, I can't really "hook" into anything before that.

Info: For each Queued command (closure) I have, I always send with it who the client is that's queing. That way I set the client before the queued command is fired. It loads the right database connection. But changing the default route() server name appears rather difficult!

I've experimented with extending the UrlGenerator class, but it appears that this is completely ignored for queued commands and only works on HTTP requests.

I've also tried adding this before the queues command is fired:

```
app('url')->forceRootUrl($client->getClientUrl());
```

It did not work. (but does work with HTTP requests)

Anyone here have an idea for how to set my own default domain for route() in CLI mode?

Comment: Maybe you can generate the link then pass it to queue as data instead of calling route('account') inside email template.

Answer (score 0):

In your environment config (.env) file, add an entry:

```
APP_URL='http://www.example.com'
```

Then in your config/app.php file change the application url from localhost:

```
----------------
Application URL
----------------
...
...
//'url' => 'http://localhost',
'url' => env('APP_URL'),
...
```

These two changes worked for me when I used the database queue driver in Laravel 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I case you have sub domain and your want to make route url with sub-domain so in this case there might be problem.

I have used this in my app. **config/app.php** file

```
...
...
//'url' => 'http://localhost',
'url' => url('/'),
...
```